# JavaScript/Jquery event problems

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been creating a to do list over the last few days although I've run into a small bug that I just can not fix.

The problem is... When I move a To Do from the "current to dos list" to the "Completed to dos list" they can not be deleted individually on the "completed to dos" page through the bin icon.

I am new to this so my code may be a mess or you may see some bad practices. If you do notice this feel free to say that as well so i can learn. :)

VIEW FULL PROJECT HERE!
https://codepen.io/beezeecode/pen/EvmBGo

```
// Transfer Li from Current to completed.
 $("ul").on("click", ".move", function(){  
  $(this).parent().remove().appendTo( "#container1");
  $(this).parent().removeClass("move comp").addClass("appendToDo comp2 comp1");
  $(this, ':nth-child(2)').remove();
});

// Delete a To dos present in the COMPLETED list. 

$("#delComp").on("click", ".delSpan", function(){
   $(this).fadeOut(500,function(){
   $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because when you move the `li` elements between lists you're appending them to the containing `div` instead of the `ul`. This in turn means that the delegated event on the delete button is not attached.

To fix this amend the `appendTo()` call in your `.move` handler:

```
$(this).parent().remove().appendTo("#delComp");
```

[**Updated Codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jLaeMV)

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that the Completed Todo is not in an `UL` anymore, so the `li` are dangling and no parent like `ul`, so the selector used here `$("ul").on("click", ".delSpan",` won't work again,

so the fix is to do , but observe the changes made to the **appendTo** `#container1 > #delComp`

```
    // Transfer Li from Current to completed.
$("ul").on("click", ".move", function(){  
  $(this).parent().remove().appendTo( "#container1 > #delComp");
  $(this).parent().removeClass("move comp").addClass("appendToDo comp2 comp1");
  $(this, ':nth-child(2)').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your `<li>` is being moved into the #container1 instead of the #delComp `<ul>`